# ExtJS 3.3.0 disable button without knowing ID

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I was wondering if its possible to target a button without it having an id, the button is being created with the following attributes at the moment.

```
{
    iconCls: 'icon-ok',
    text: 'Save'
}
```

If I add id: 'saveButton' to it i can simply call;

```
Ext.getCmp('saveButton').setDisabled(true);
```

and it works fine ... But I can't give the button an ID for different reasons.

I have details of the window that the button is created in if that helps

```
id: 'updateDialog',
modal: true,
width: {$windowWidth},
height: {$windowHeight},
labelAlign: 'top',
title: "Update",
layout:'vbox',
```

Comment: What, outside of the button, do you have a reference to? Post some more of the surrounding structure.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I have updated my question if that helps .. THe button is located inside the window

Comment: You could try the `find` or `findByType` methods on the window. You may also want to look at `ref`: http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Component.html#cfg-Ext.Component-ref Though it can be a bit brittle.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thank you .. I will check that out

Comment: This is not enough code, it depends on the relationship between the code that will call `setDisabled` and the button.

Answer (score 1):

For legacy ExtJS like 3.3.0, you can use something like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var btn1 = new Ext.Button({
        iconCls: 'icon-ok',
        text: 'Save 01 (ok)'
    });

    var btn2 = new Ext.Button({
        iconCls: 'icon-not-ok',
        text: 'Save 02 (not ok)'
    });

    var btn3 = new Ext.Button({
        iconCls: 'icon-ok',
        text: 'Save 03 (ok)'
    });

    var btn4 = new Ext.Button({
        iconCls: 'icon-not-ok',
        text: 'Save 04 (not ok)'
    });

    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: document.body,
        title: 'Panel',
        items: [ btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4 ]
    });

    panel.items.each( function( element, index, array ) {
        if ( element.iconCls === 'icon-ok' ) {
            element.setDisabled( true );
        }
    });

});
```

I added the four buttons to a panel and iterate through the items property of it. This property is a Ext.util.MixedCollection. I think your buttons are inside some container, so this will probably work. Another possiblitity is to process the Ext.getBody() element, but this will need more offort to detect what you want. Live example here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27nh

For ExtJS 4 and above, you can use Ext.ComponentQuery.query function.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    iconCls: 'icon-ok',
    text: 'Save 01'
});

Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    iconCls: 'icon-ok',
    text: 'Save 02'
});

Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    iconCls: 'icon-ok',
    text: 'Save 03'
});

var components = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[iconCls=icon-ok]');
components.forEach( function( element, index, array ) {
    element.setDisabled(true);
});
```

I'm pretty rusty in ExtJS, since my last use of it was in 2009 :D

Comment: Hey, Thanks for that ... Could i also set the query to [text=Save]?

Comment: Pretty sure component querying wasn't introduced until Ext 4.x.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli ... Is there an alternative for 3.3.0?

Comment: Im getting the following error - Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: @BigJobbies Its because my code is for ExtJS 4 and above. I updated the code to allow something like you want in legacy ExtJS.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Fixed ;)